# Scala Sax parser unable to process <!DOCTYPE XML>

Tags: xml, scala, parsing

I want to parse XML files I get from sources beyong my control (specifically Suunto sporttesters). When loading them using scala `XML.load()` they load fine, however I would prefer SAX (pull) parsing for better performance. However the pull parsers seems not to be happy about the file header. See following example:

```
import scala.io.Source
import scala.xml.pull.XMLEventReader
val text = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<MovesCount MoveslinkVersion="1.2.41.0" TimeZone="60" >
 <Device sn="Quest_2596420792" >
  <Model info="DEVICE;INT;R" >120</Model>
  <Name info="DEVICE;TEXT;R" >Quest</Name>
  <FullName info="DEVICE;TEXT;R" >Suunto Quest</FullName>
  <SerialNumber info="DEVICE;INT;R" >2596420792</SerialNumber>
  </Device>
</MovesCount>"""

val src = Source.fromString(text)

for (ev <- new XMLEventReader(src)) {
  println(ev)
}
```

This prints an error while parsing:

> :2:14: whitespace expected

When I delete the line containing the `DOCTYPE` or change it to `<!DOCTYPE xml >`, the error goes away and the file parses fine.

Is this a bug in the xml pull parser? If it is, is there some possible workaround? XML comes from external sources way beyond my control.

Answer (score 0):

After trying another parser ([Aalto XML](https://github.com/FasterXML/aalto-xml)) I think the document is really malformed beyond hope and one needs to fix it before feeding it into the parser. My workaround is that I skip the DOC type header when present using `PushbackInputStream` to transform the input stream.